# Clearing a file over a given size C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a program which runs every so often and I'd like to keep the log file limited in size, to around 1MB or so. I've figured out how to get the file size using tellp and seekp, but everything I try to do to delete the file doesn't work. Here's what my latest code looks like:

```
     std::ofstream myfile("file.txt");
     long begin = myfile.tellp();
     myfile.seekp(0,std::ios::end);
     long end = myfile.tellp();
     std::cout << "File size is " << (end - begin) << "\n";
     if((end - begin) > 1048576) //1048576 bytes in a megabyte
     {
        //position the cursor to the beginning of the file
        //I don't know if this is necessary but it seemed worth trying
        myfile.seekp(0,std::ios::beg);
        //opening with trunc erases previous contents (supposedly)
        std::cout << "Clearing file\n";
        myfile.open("file.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
        myfile << "File has reached limit, clearing...\n";
        myfile.close();
     }
     myfile.open("file.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
     myfile << "Starting program\n";
     myfile.close();
```

The if statement is hit, since the program outputs "Clearing file", but the file is not cleared and on top of that, "File has reached limit..." is nowhere to be found in the file. But "Starting program" is in there. Any ideas?

Comment: You just want to "unlink()" the oversized file, then create a new one with your markers.

Comment: What do you mean "unlink", looking through google that doesn't appear to be a C++ fstream function.

Comment: `unlink` isn't a fstream function, it's a standard C library function that deletes the file itself. Although opening the file with `ios::out` and `ios::trunc` should work just fine. I suspect you just need to close the file before you try to re-open it with `ios::trunc`

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. *slaps forehead out of frustration* Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unlink` isn't a fstream function, it's a standard C library function that deletes the file itself.

Although opening the file with `ios::out` and `ios::trunc` should work just fine. I suspect you just need to close the file before you try to re-open it with `ios::trunc`.